# Cannot drop a column in Sybase table

Tags: database

I tried to drop a column in a Sybase table but I am getting this exception:

> Can't allocate space for object 'TABLE1' in database 'SAMPLE' because
>   'default' segment is full/has no free extents. If you ran out of space
>   in syslogs, dump the transaction log. Otherwise, use ALTER DATABASE to
>   increase the size of the segment.

I already tried ALTER DATABASE but to no avail. Please help.

Comment: did you check any space is left of your DB server ?
Also as suggested did you delete transaction log files ?

Comment: how do i check for the space left of my DB server? and what is the safe way to delete transaction log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [this](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/svrtsg/@Generic__BookTextView/22674;pt=22666)?